# Cannot access appdelegate instance variable from related View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

My app name is **PropertiesSearch** so the project contains the following files:

```
PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.h
PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.m
PropertiesSearchViewController.h
PropertiesSearchViewController.m
```

I declared an instance variable (ListingNav) in PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.h like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class PropertiesSearchViewController;

@interface PropertiesSearchAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *ListingNav;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *ListingNav;

@end
```

and in PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.m, I added

```
@synthesize ListingNav;
```

Now I'm trying to access ListingNav from PropertiesSearchViewController.m like this:

```
PropertiesSearchAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PropertiesSearchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// Then here I can easily do appDelegate.ListingNav etc...
```

But debugger is showing:

> Use of undeclared identifier PropertiesSearchAppDelegate

Should I import **PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.h** in **PropertiesSearchViewController.h** ?

Thx in advance for your help

Stephane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import *PropertiesSearchAppDelegate.h* in *PropertiesSearchViewController.h*.

To let a class know about another class, you should either **import the class** or add **@class directive**. Adding *@class directive* just lets the class aware that another class exists. In your case, you should import *PropertiesSearchAppDelegate* as you are trying to access the members of the class.